# Redis key disappears without warning

Tags: redis

I have been using redis for quite some time and currently at version 2.3.11. We are witnessing some of the keys disappear even though, they don't have any timeout set (I checked using ttl for keys that did not disappear? Also checked pretty much every attribute set using 'info' but cant seem to get a clue? Anyone seen this?

Note: We store the same keys in 2 places (PostGres and Redis) and same application writes or
      removes. There is no application running.

Comment: is your `maxmemory-policy` set to `allkeys-lru`?

Comment: akonsu - no, # maxmemory-policy volatile-lru, so it is not even set.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm in the same spot: two years in, all of sudden keys are disappearing, without any code or environment changes.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30510254/redis-keys-disappear

Answer (score 1):

Please check the maxmemory-policy. If you're using AWS Elasticache note that the default is volatile-lru: [Parameters for Redis](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/CacheParameterGroups.Redis.html)